# How can I configure php-barcode to use code128 encoding?

Tags: php, barcode

How do I configure [php-barcode](http://www.ashberg.de/php-barcode) to generate code with the code128 encoding?

I've installed php-barcode, but I don't know how to change the encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs in the README included with the source:

> **function barcode_encode(code, encoding)**
>
> encodes $code with $encoding using genbarcode OR built-in encoder
>
> if you don't have genbarcode only EAN-13/ISBN is possible

So you need to have genbarcode installed, and then just call `$barcode = barcode_encode($yourCode, '128');`

You should take a moment and read through the README, as it explains how to use the library.